# How to install and use JFreeChart in Play Framework

Tags: html, playframework, jfreechart

I'm using play 1.2.4 and I would like to add [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) in to my project

Does anyone know how to install and a simple use? I have try google for examples but didn't find any with play framework.

thanks in advance

dependencies file

```
require:
    - play
    - jfree ->jfreechart 1.0.13
```

Answer (score 3):

Play project's dependencies are configured in `conf/dependencies.yml` file (see [Play documentation about dependency management](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/dependency)).

Since various versions of JFreeChart can be found from central Maven repository, all you have to do is add the following (last) line into your dependencies file:

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - ...
    - org.jfree -> jfreechart 1.0.14
```

After that, run `play dependencies` command, which should download the needed JARs and install them into `lib` folder of your project. You should now be set to use JFreeChart classes in your project.

Comment: i try to make play install jfree and it's doesn't exist

Comment: For reference, [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) version 1.0.14 is current.

Comment: @Daniel - `play install` command is for Play modules only. There is no JFreeChart module (AFAIK), so the command will not work. I think you will need to describe more clearly what goes wrong if you follow my advice - otherwise I can't help.

Comment: thanks, it work, i have try to find some manual but i cant, do you know how to work in the play framework, do i create and rende it or do in the view?

Comment: JFreeChart can produce the charts as images, doesn't it? In that case you might not need to have much in views at all, just create the chart and use `RenderBinary` call in the controller to output the image.

Comment: and how do i rende the others? put in a new question for me to guive you another +1 ;) thanks